# Mul object has no attribute real

Tags: python, import, ipython

I'm using the code from this link: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/127469-numerical-inversion-of-laplace-transforms-through-/

to compute the inverse Laplace transform of a complex equation.

I've copied and pasted this into my ipython notebook, but after running the inversion on the function I need to invert, I get this error:

AttributeError: 'Mul' object has no attribute 'real'

Specifically, in the link above, the error occurs on this line: (K[j]*Fs(a[j]/t)).real

I think it has something to do with my imports and things but I'm not sure as I'm a complete beginner to python.  But here are my imports:

import cmath as cm
from cmath import *

import sympy as sym
from sympy import *

I know you're not suppose to use from  import *, but I was trying everything to see if I could get this to work.  And the cmath is included from the link above.

Any insight into this error would be great, thanks!

Comment: Don't `import *`. You may have replaced one of the things you needed with an identically-named thing from sympy.

Comment: remove `from cmath import *`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int`, `float`, `complex` types have `.real`  attribute in Python:

```
>>> 1 .real
1
>>> 1. .real
1.0
>>> 1j.real
0.0
```

Define `K` and `Fs` so that the result is a number.

If the result is a symbolic expression produced by `sympy`; you could try `re` function to get a real part.

Comment: awesome, thanks. Yeah the computation of K * Fs returns a sympy and so I put complex around K*Fs and then called .real on that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying the code, try clicking the *Download* button. The code works fine in Python 2.7.6, something must have gone wrong when you copied.

Comment: Yeah the code does run fine by itself. I had copied and pasted it into  my existing notebook . Is there a way to download it and then reference it in my current notebook? Just for reference, the end goal is to put this all on the internet for public viewing.